How to use __init__.py to create a clean API?
Problem Description:
I am trying to create a local API for my team. I think I understand broadly the mechanics of _init_.py. Let's say we have the below package structure:
API/
├── __init__.py         # Top-level package init file
└── core/               
    ├── __init__.py     # Core module init file
    ├── calculator.py   
    └── exceptions.py   

Now if I build my API with empty _init_.py files, and then import API in my script, I won't be able to do something like:
import API
API.core
API.core.calculator

Because the submodules have not been imported specifically. What I need to do is to add into the following into my top-level _init_.py:
from . import core

And the following into my core module _init_.py:
from . import calculator
from . import exceptions

Now, when I do this, all imports I am making in my calculator.py or exceptions.py such as numpy or pandas are actually available through my package as follows:
API.core.calculator.numpy

Question 1: What are the best practices to prevent imported libraries to show through my API ?
On the same theme, let's say I want to access my calculator.py functions directly through the core keyword (let's assume _all_ variables are safely set up). Then I can add the following into my core module _init_.py
from .calculator import *
from .exceptions import *

which then allows me to do:
API.core.my_function()

But then again, I can also call API.core.calculator.my_function() at the same time, which might be confusing for users.
2. How to prevent imported functions to be available through both my package name and module name ?
I tried mixing up the approaches, but with no results, please help !

The typical best practice is to define an __all__ list in each sub-module with names you want the sub-module to export so that the parent module can import just those names with a star import.
Names that you don't want exposed should be named with a leading underscore by convention so that the linters will warn the users if they try to import a "private" name.
So in your example case, your API/core/calculator.py will look like:
import numpy as _numpy

__all__ = ['my_function']

def my_function(): ...

And then API/core/__init__.py will star-import what's exported by calculator (that is, just my_function):
from .calculator import *

which then allows you to do:
API.core.my_function()

but not:
API.core._numpy
API.core.calculator._numpy

Note that the user can always do import API.core.calculator explicitly to access _numpy in that sub-module, but that is just how the module namespace works as there is nothing really private in Python.
Also note that a star import will not import names with leading underscores so if you do follow the convention of naming your "private" variables as such you don't even need to define an __all__ list.
Excerpt from the documentation of More on Modules:

There is even a variant to import all names that a module defines:
>>>
from fibo import *
fib(500)
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377

This imports all names except those beginning with an underscore (_).


Thanks for your answer. Does that mean that the intended use to make a clean API is more to call functions through the package name (and not through the module name)? What kind of tricks are libraries like seaborn, which imports matplotlib internally, use to hide those libraries from the namespace?

Python has a consenting adults policy and doesn't enforce private names at the language level. The best practice is to name your "private" variables with leading underscores. I've updated the answer accordingly then.

You're welcome. I just added another note that a star import wouldn't import names with leading underscores so you may not need to define __all__ at all if you do follow the naming convention.
